# Querying with type mapped columns in Slick

Tags: scala, slick

How would you write this query in SLICK?

```
DB.withSession  {
  implicit session =>
    Tokens.where(_.expirationTime < DateTime.now ).delete
}
```

DateTime.now is of type org.joda.time.DateTime

and _.expirationTime is a type mapped column of the same type.

I get this error

```
[error] UserService.scala:80: value < is not a member of scala.slick.lifted.Column[org.joda.time.DateTime]
[error]         Tokens.where(_.expirationTime < DateTime.now ).delete
[error]                                       ^
[error] one error found
```

right now with the query in this form.

Answer (score 4):

My guess is that the JodaTime types are not supported types out of the box for slick.  If you changed that column to a `java.sql.Timestamp` and used a `Timestamp` as your comparison value, things would work.  If you want to use joda types in your slick column mappings, you might want to look into this:

https://github.com/tototoshi/slick-joda-mapper

Answer (score 1):

Importing `com.github.tototoshi.slick.JodaSupport._` fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do:

Let's assume that your Token class looks like this and that you use mysql:

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime
import com.github.tototoshi.slick.JdbcJodaSupport._
import play.api.db.slick.Config.driver.simple._

case class Token(
                  id: Option[Long]
                  expirationTime: Option[DateTime]                  
                 )

class Tokens(tag: Tag) extends Table[Token](tag, "Token") {
  def id = column[Long]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc, O.Nullable)
  def expirationTime = column[DateTime]("expirationTime", O.Nullable)  

  def * = (id.?, expirationTime.?) <> (Token.tupled, Token.unapply)

}
```

Eg. dependencies:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "2.1.0-M2",
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick" % "0.8.0-M1",
  "com.github.tototoshi" %% "slick-joda-mapper" % "1.2.0",
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.26"
)
```

Then all you need to do is:

```
import com.github.tototoshi.slick.JdbcJodaSupport._


DB.withSession  {
  implicit session =>
    Tokens.where(_.expirationTime < DateTime.now ).delete
}
```

If you use any other db than mysql you need to alter your imports and dependencies.